# How to apply qemu:env command line to virt-manager? (libvirt)

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt, virt-manager

I need to apply this fix

```
<qemu:env name="MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE" value="i965"/>
```

to my virt-manager VM.

However, I don't know where to put it.

I tried editing the XML like this:

```
<domain type="kvm">
  <name>unsafe_code_2</name>
  <qemu:commandline>
      <qemu:env name="MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE" value="i965"/>
  </qemu:commandline>
```

but when I click apply, virt-manager simply erases

```
  <qemu:commandline>
      <qemu:env name="MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE" value="i965"/>
  </qemu:commandline>
```

so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

It won't get removed if you declare the QEMU XML schema on the `<domain>` element:

```
<domain xmlns:qemu="http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0" type="kvm">
   ...
</domain>
```

**or** just declare it on the element you need it for:

```
<qemu:commandline xmlns:qemu="http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0">
    <qemu:env name="MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE" value="i965"/>
</qemu:commandline>
```

*(but note that virt-manager will reformat your XML to use the first option)*

(Reference: https://www.libvirt.org/kbase/qemu-passthrough-security.html)

Another option would be using the following command:

```
virt-xml VM_NAME_HERE --edit --qemu-commandline env=MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965
```